# When using a query to populate my listbox the last column is always blank

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, listbox

I can move around the items in the select statement and whichever item is last always is blank in my listbox when it displays the data. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. When I test the query it pulls the all the info from the table correctly. I don't know if I have something setup wrong in the listbox or what.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim frm As Form, rs As Recordset
Dim nb As String, cs As String, s As String, ss As String
Dim od As String, cd As String, t As String, tt As String, st As String
Dim sql_select As String, sql_from As String, sql_where As String

sql_select = "SELECT nc.[Status], nc.[NC Number], nc.[Date_Open], nc.[CS_Build], nc.[Section], nc.[Sub-Section], nc.[TPS], nc.[TPS_Type], nc.[Date_Closed] "
sql_from = sql_query + "FROM nc "
sql_where = sql_query + "WHERE " & nb & " And " & cs & " And " & s & " And " & ss & " And " & od & " And " & cd & " And " & t & " And " & tt & " And " & st & ";"

Me.lstSearch.RowSource = sql_select + sql_from + sql_where

End Sub
```

Here is the resulting query...

```
SELECT nc.[NC Number], nc.[Date_Open], nc.[CS_Build], nc.[Section], nc.[Sub-Section], nc.[TPS], nc.[TPS_Type], nc.[Date_Closed], nc.[Status]
FROM nc
WHERE nc.[CS_Build] = "CS1" And nc.[Section] = "FS" And nc.[Status] = "OPEN";
```

And here is what it returns...

```
NC Number   Date_Open   CS_Build    Section Sub-Section TPS        TPS_Type Date_Closed Status
NCS0004726  5/5/2022    CS1         FS                  Internal    S-520               OPEN
NCS0004762  5/6/2022    CS1         FS      System      Other       Foam                OPEN
```

This is what the form looks like. As you can see the Status column is empty where it should show OPEN. I can rearrange the items in the select statement and always the last column is empty while all the others are correct. I can change my search criteria and it does not matter.
[image]

Comment: What do we know without the resulting SQL?

Comment: If you have 9 columns but the 'Number of columns' of the listbox is set to 8 (for example), you cannot see the last column.

Comment: Looks like ColumnCount and even ColumnWidths can't be the issue as all headers are being displayed. I would add a `Debug.Print sql_select + sql_from + sql_where` before changing the Recordsource and see if it's actually what you think it is. And copy/paste/run from the SQL View of a new query to see what comes out.

Comment: Are your date open/closed fields actually Date Fields in your table? Do they have anything specified in the field Format? Your other question shows you using the criteria `od = "nc.[Date_Open] = """ & Me.txtOpenDate & """"`  instead of using the Microsoft Access Date delimiter `#`

Comment: Still not sure why it doesn't show all the columns, but I found a work around. I added another column and now it shows all 10 correctly.